# Should I get a gigabit router with or without ipv6 support?

Tags: performance, wireless-router, ipv6, gigabit-ethernet, ipv4

I'm in the process of getting a gigabit router so i can transfer files faster to and from my Lacie Network Space. I found a gigabit Router. Its performance is really good, however it doesnt support ipv6.

On the other hand, the world is running out of ipv4 addresses and we has already implemented ipv6. I'm wondering if i should get a router with ipv6 support or i should stick to some router without ipv6 support but with high performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Also, don't repost a question that you have already had closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv4 is going to be around for a while yet.

How do you make your Internet connection? If it's through ADSL or cable, you don't need to get IPv6 yet.

Comment: My ISP is Shaw. The cable go through the modem, then the modem is connected to my current router and this router is connected by computers and the Lacie network drive. Usually i keep my router for about 5-7 years, till then, is ipv4 still around?

Comment: Your router is internal, just like mine. I'm also with Shaw. The cable modem, as far as I'm aware, is only IPv4 and will probably remain IPv4 for a while yet. At any rate, my point is that even if your external interface becomes IPv6, internally IPv4 will still work.

Answer (score 4):

The state of IPv6 in router hardware is... actually pretty abysmal. The best thing is to find a router that can run DD-WRT or OpenWRT and then configure it for IPv6.